# Transform from normal coordinate sytsem to axis cs

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to clip beam1 with wall1 (respectively, remove everything left of the blue curve. Since this is part of a lot bigger picture, my axis is set at some position determined by other nodes (thus the (-2,-2) to mimic that) and it is also quite hard to adjust everything with another coordinate system as the one chosen for the axis. I think what makes this not work is the missing Transformation of coordinates that are not in the axis coordinate System (beam1) to it. I had a look at the documentation of pgfplots and tikz, and searched/played around for 2+ hours without success, so I'd very happy if some magitikzian has an idea :)
I hoped for something like (normal cs: 0,0) instead of (axis cs: 0,0), but I did not find something along the lines of that.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,intersections}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{dummy.txt}
5.03648495306   1.09038397672
5.01378548253   1.05075979225
5.00918627445   1.0427313368
5.0060192168    1.03395705465
4.99115561425   0.992778008709
4.98788405384   0.983713799765
4.98594043328   0.972593374231
4.97652201546   0.91870272348
4.97473578036   0.908481939072
4.97473572614   0.897738495243
4.97473579127   0.844343058888
4.97473587042   0.834987856057
4.97681347795   0.823084172075
4.98736438778   0.762630408193
4.9892476584    0.751838955382
4.99571175799   0.733877351099
5.02675983741   0.647603580722
5.03435174668   0.626507772246
5.04414173938   0.609366384901
5.08427341869   0.539099541986
5.09246958065   0.524748715056
5.12556703002   0.486370583367
5.14007762355   0.469545145319
5.18742387873   0.422055772173
5.25924511484   0.360399853435
5.26591771754   0.354671648752
5.28478869109   0.334676276399
5.36193861  0.252928953841
5.37442349882   0.239700037322
5.38132838473   0.230842564693
5.40947450219   0.194738099536
5.42128576009   0.179586998835
5.42659494014   0.170922909719
5.49041269437   0.066774013977
5.49870242684   0.0484401456582
5.50779789189   0.028323505478
5.51133317725   0.0187659961915
5.52206445757   -0.0102450240511
5.52511556082   -0.0184934971343
5.52722649143   -0.0264186580303
5.53219881486   -0.0450857390135
5.53350109239   -0.0499748730874
5.53468666873   -0.0559010019409
5.53704181123   -0.0676741231577
5.53765106565   -0.0707195547829
5.53912193456   -0.0821962928917
5.54861586205   -0.156273043417
5.55002071737   -0.16723447387
5.55077582712   -0.177035977027
5.5536850942    -0.214801425597
5.55424196207   -0.222028386335
5.55399675007   -0.232795526715
5.55307164523   -0.273416433445
5.55276643944   -0.286807696465
5.55138499528   -0.30608578923
5.54631050394   -0.376890961682
5.54554218539   -0.387610388649
5.5420298094    -0.403444093773
5.5296877408    -0.459082468429
5.52661030624   -0.472955744569
5.52070340061   -0.49219304209
5.51025364727   -0.526224780755
5.49720034651   -0.554297970607
5.45693117032   -0.640902961948
5.44930029532   -0.657314238872
5.44790226432   -0.659724656342
5.43461352553   -0.682634789966
5.42895036248   -0.694819383448
5.41833096289   -0.717669013695
5.4125994934    -0.730001820474
5.40709630461   -0.750091968084
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (plot) at (-2,-2);
        \begin{axis}[at={(plot)},hide axis,width=116.5,height=116.5,clip=false,xmin=4.4,xmax=6.4,ymin=-1,ymax=1,xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty, very thin,xshift=-1.25cm,yshift=-1.25cm]
            %\clip plot file {dummy.txt};   <-- commented to show where wall1 is
            \path [draw,blue,name path global=wall1] plot file {dummy.txt};
            \path [fill=orange, name path global=beam1] (0,-1) -- ++ (189:4) -- ++ (0,-0.25) -- (0,-1.25) -- cycle; % <-- is there something like (normal cs:0,-1) ?
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `rel axis cs` ?

Comment: Then I am still not in the "normal" coordinate System, I think. compare using `rel axis cs' vs. just moving the draw command outside the axis Environment, only in the latter case it correctly cuts the blue line.

Comment: I was able to make some progress by moving beam1 outside the axis environment, but to clip you need wall1 to SURROUND the image.  Actually, you don't need the axis environment at all, but it would help to know what units the width and height are supposed to be.

Comment: One can read data using pgfplotstable or csvtools and construct a scaled and shifted array of (x,y) coordinates in a macro.  That would allow you to add extra coordinates to complete the clipping box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something like `normal cs` which is `canvas cs:` as detailed in the PGF manual.  Similarly there is also `canvas polar cs:`.  Keep in mind that the units are in `pt` there and the syntax requires explicit keys for the coordinates.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,intersections}

% omitted file, see question

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (plot) at (-2,-2);
        \begin{axis}[at={(plot)},hide axis,width=116.5,height=116.5,clip=false,xmin=4.4,xmax=6.4,ymin=-1,ymax=1,xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty, very thin,xshift=-1.25cm,yshift=-1.25cm]
            %\clip plot file {dummy.txt};   <-- commented to show where wall1 is
            \path [draw,blue,name path global=wall1] plot file {dummy.txt};
            \path [fill=orange, name path global=beam1] (canvas cs:x=0cm,y=-1cm) -- ++ (canvas polar cs:angle=189,radius=4cm) -- ++ (canvas cs:x=0cm,y=-0.25cm) -- (canvas cs:x=0cm,y=-1.25cm) -- cycle; % <-- is there something like (normal cs:0,-1) ?
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Admittedly I hoped for some way to avoid giving explicit units of measure, somehow that does not feel right.